What's the thickness of Playtive Clippys baseplates?
It appears Lidl's Playtive Clippys clone brand has now added baseplates to their portfolio:
https://www.lidl.de/p/playtive-clippys-bauplatten-6-teilig/p100379313
Are these comparable in thickness to LEGO's baseplates (the ones that LEGO is phasing out in favour of regular plates and the new road system)?

Auto-translate assures me they're "Compatible with all commercially available clamping bricks" I'll have to keep my eye out here in the UK if they ever arrive

@Zhaph-BenDuguid: Yes, that is what the German text says. And it's true, my children already have several Clippys sets and they combine flawlessly with LEGO bricks.
